# Manipulating Media uploader

Tags: uploads, thickbox

Ok. Going to try and explain this as best as I can, so bare with me. Anyway, I'm trying to include the default media uploader as a part of my plugin.

Currently, I've successfully managed to use the filter `attachment_fields_to_edit` to hide most of the input fields, leaving only the title & alternate text fields, alongside a custom submit button. When clicked, this button gets the images URL and places it into a `div` on the parent page.

Anyway, so here is my problem. Everything regarding the uploader itself is functioning how I want it to, but currently the filter is applying itself to the media uploader in posts, pages, the media library, etc. I only want the alternative fields & custom button to show within my plugin, but not elsewhere.

I've tried everything, but I cannot get it to work. I managed to apply my own query to the media-upload.php URL, and that way I could make the alternative fields only show within my plugin on the thickbox 'library' tab, but when uploading a new image the default fields were showing because Wordpress uses an alternative file to upload the image; async-upload.php.

Here is the entire function: http://pastebin.com/5vpecMvL

Just some information on the various functions: `riva_slider_pro_info()` is a function that returns an array of values. `riva_slider_pro_uri( $search )` gets $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] and stores it in a variable, search its for the $search parameter and return true or false.

In the 'libary' tab within the media uploader thickbox, it is returning `true` because I have passed a additional query onto the media-upload.php URL (for example, 'media-upload.php?post_id=0$slideshow=true&type=image&TB_iframe=1'). BUT, it is returning `false` after the user has just uploaded a new image within the same thickbox, because it uses the async-upload.php file instead. Not sure how I could pass the query onto this URL, if it would be possible to make it work that way.

I realise this may be hard to follow, but I've tried my best to explain it. I'm literally pulling my hair out over this one and spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure it out. Appreciate any comments or suggestions, or ideally a solution! Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to filter the fields in certain places but not in others? i've always hid the fields w/ jquery, but i like this idea much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i ended up doing was launching the thickbox uploaded manually via a jquery click event.  then with setInterval i was able to hide the pieces i wanted.

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
  $('.specialclass').click(function() { 
       //get post id from somewhere (for me this was the row column
    string = $(this).parents('tr.type-portfolio').attr('id'); 
    if(/post-(\d+)/.exec(string)[1]) post_id = parseInt(/post-(\d+)/.exec(string)[1], 10);

    tbframe_interval = setInterval(function() {

       //remove url, alignment and size fields- auto set to null, none and full respectively                        
       $('#TB_iframeContent').contents().find('.url').hide().find('input').val('');
       $('#TB_iframeContent').contents().find('.align').hide().find('input:radio').filter('[value="none"]').attr('checked', true);
       $('#TB_iframeContent').contents().find('.image-size').hide().find('input:radio').filter('[value="full"]').attr('checked', true);

    }, 2000);

    if(post_id) tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+post_id+'&type=image&tab=library&TB_iframe=true'); //tab sets the opened TB window to show library by default

    return false;
   });
});
```